# Python sklearn poly regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm stuck solving this issue for two days now. I have some datapoints I put in a `scatter plot` and get this:

[image]

Which is nice, but now I also want to add a regression line, so I had a look at this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-underfitting-overfitting-py) from sklearn and changed the code to this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

degrees = [3, 4, 5]
X = combined[['WPI score']]
y = combined[['CPI score']]

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
for i in range(len(degrees)):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, len(degrees), i + 1)
    plt.setp(ax, xticks=(), yticks=())

    polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degrees[i], include_bias=False)
    linear_regression = LinearRegression()
    pipeline = Pipeline([("polynomial_features", polynomial_features), ("linear_regression", linear_regression)])
    pipeline.fit(X, y)

    # Evaluate the models using crossvalidation
    scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)

    X_test = X #np.linspace(0, 1, len(combined))
    plt.plot(X, pipeline.predict(X_test), label="Model")
    plt.scatter(X, y, label="CPI-WPI")
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.title("Degree {}\nMSE = {:.2e}(+/- {:.2e})".format(degrees[i], -scores.mean(), scores.std()))
plt.savefig(pic_path + 'multi.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

which has the following output:

[image]

Note that `X` and `y` are both `DataFrames` of size `(151, 1)`. I can post the content of X and y too, if necessary.

What I want is a nice smooth line, but I seem not to be able to figure out, how to do this.

**[Edit]**

The question here is: How do I get a single smooth, curvy polynomial line instead of multiple ones with seemingly random pattern.

**[Edit 2]**

The problem is, when I use the `linspace` like this:

```
X_test = np.linspace(1, 4, 151)
X_test = X_test[:, np.newaxis]
```

I get a even more random pattern:

[image]

Comment: What **exactly** is the question here? These are nice smooth lines! What's the problem?

Comment: I want a single smooth polynomial line with curves. At the moment I have multiple lines, that seem randomly connected.

Comment: While i don't like the way of using matplotlib here, the problem is probably within the shape of ```X_test```. Check the shape or output of the prediction. It looks, like you are predicting multiple stuff in parallel and plot all.

Comment: I'm still quite new to python, what's wrong with the `matplotlib`? and I did set `X_test` to my original `X`, because I am not sure, what else to put in there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with matplotlib; i just would have used it differently. And yes, your content of X_test is the problem here. Why not doing the same as in the example (as you are using this as reference). Read up some docs on matplotlib to understand, what x and y should be within plt.plot().

Comment: I tried that too, but with unsatisfying result (see edit 2). Is there a way to "dump" the content of a dataset? Then I could post it here, too.

Comment: Sure, but these are basics. Take some time to read more about pandas, numpy, scikit-learn and matplotlib. I think it would be easier to throw away the pandas dataframe and convert it so some pure numpy-array before doing these steps (at least for a beginner). For debugging purposes: print out regularly the shapes and dtypes of your data before any step (e.g. X.shape). The good thing is, that you got some benchmark-code to compare with.

Comment: ah, now I got it, my mistake was the `X_test` and then plot against `X_test` and the prediction of `X_test`.

Comment: That's good to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to set the code like following:

```
X_test = np.linspace(min(X['GPI score']), max(X['GPI score']), X.shape[0])
X_test = X_test[:, np.newaxis]
plt.plot(X_test, pipeline.predict(X_test), label="Model")
```

Which yields the following result (a much nicer, single smooth line)

[image: Model with degree 1 to 6]